# How to make scanner and keyListener cooperate with themselves?

Tags: java, input, keylistener

I'm trying to create a program similar to Linux/Win terminal. 
I'm stuck because i want to create sth like command history.
I'm using Scanner to read an input but while it's waitng for input KeyListener doesn't respond. So my question is "How to make keyListener and Scanner cooperate with each other ?"

```
public class main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    KeyListener key = new KeyListener() {

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            System.out.println("tutej.");
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            System.out.println("test.");
        }
    };
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(true) {
        System.out.println("Write sth :");
        scan.nextLine();
    }


}
```

}

Comment: A `KeyListener` is attached to an AWT component and processes keystrokes on that component.  A `Scanner` as you have declared it reads `System.in`. They are two completely separate things.  An input stream (what the scanner reads) is only the data, with no keyboard events.  If you wanted to you could attach a scanner to a stream into which you fed the data _after_ processing the key events yourself.  But you'd have to write that code.

Comment: Also it does not follow that you need to use a scanner because you want to maintain command history.  Maybe an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)?

Comment: While program is waiting for user to put a command.User can just write a command or press a <- or -> to choose between commands put eralier by him.